# How do I deal with the "input signal out of range" problem while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, gpu

I am using GTX 1070 as GPU, it works fine on Windows 10 with my monitor, but when I try installing either Ubuntu or Fedora from the USB disk, the monitor turned down and shown “Input signal out of range! Current Mode: H=34.3kHz V=30Hz Change Mode to 1920*1820 -60 Hz”.

Now I simply want to have my Linux installed, through whatever way.

The things I have tried:

1. Connect HDMI to HDMI
2. Connect HDMI through HDMI->VGA socket to VGA

Please help me with this issue, I have been troubled with this for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out finally by installing the ubuntu with the video card on my motherboard (In other word, connect your screen to any video card that could at least allow you to install the system first, then switch back after you've set up). Once you have installed the system, go downloading the right version of NVIDIA driver, then you can install the driver and switch back to GTX1070 while you reboot. Hope that helps.